# What is the significance of ?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0 in the SSO sp initiated flow

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs, service-provider

I am Using SAML 2.0 in the SSO SP initiated flow. I have configured logout url as `"https://{DNS_name}/adfs/ls/"` and i am getting the below error.

> Error:- System.Xml.XmlException: MSIS0006: A required attribute is not
>   present: ID.

Note:- I am not getting this error if i configure logout URL as `"https://{DNS_name}/adfs/ls?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0"`.

Que :- Why am i getting ID related errors if not configuring cleanup part(?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0). i am not getting the significance of cleanup part in the logout URL.

I have read that "The wsignoutcleanup1.0 message is an instruction to relying parties to delete the cached session state for the specified user."

> Complete Error:- Encountered error during federation passive request.
>
> Additional Data
>
> Protocol Name:
>
> Relying Party:
>
> Exception details:  System.Xml.XmlException: MSIS0006: A required
>   attribute is not present: ID.    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadCommonAttributes(XmlReader
>   reader, SamlMessage message)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadLogoutRequest(XmlReader
>   reader)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadSamlMessage(XmlReader
>   reader, NamespaceContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlBindingSerializer.ReadProtocolMessage(String
>   encodedSamlMessage)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlBindingSerializer.CreateFromNameValueCollection(Uri
>   baseUrl, NameValueCollection collection)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpPostSamlBindingSerializer.ReadMessage(Uri
>   requestUrl, NameValueCollection form)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlMessageFactory.CreateMessage(WrappedHttpListenerRequest
>   httpRequest)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlContextFactory.CreateProtocolContextFromRequest(WrappedHttpListenerRequest
>   request, ProtocolContext& protocolContext)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.CreateProtocolContext(WrappedHttpListenerRequest
>   request)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.GetProtocolHandler(WrappedHttpListenerRequest
>   request, ProtocolContext& protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler&
>   protocolHandler)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext
>   context)

Comment: `/adfs/ls` is the right single logout URL in ADFS implementation of SAML, you can verify this by pulling SAML metadata from ADFS.  `?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0` should not be needed and it belongs to a different protocol altogether (WS-Federation). I haven't seen this error message but it's something in your SAML logout request that ADFS doesn't like.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because you're outside of spec. The `?wa` parameter defines the action that you want to happen, i.e. "This REQUIRED parameter specifies the action to be performed." ([Source](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/v1.2/os/ws-federation-1.2-spec-os.html#_Toc223175012)).

It's not specific to this sign-out action... it's any action.

Comment: I am agree with your point..but the Error says "A required ID attribute is not present"while not including ?wa parameter. and if i include the ?wa parameter then there wont be any error. Is there any relation b/w ID and ?wa parameter @Kellen

Comment: I'm pretty sure the required attribute it's talking about is the action parameter. It doesn't know how to handle the request because you're not telling it what you want to do without that query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I work at Microsoft boii.  For SAML you want to use the https://sts.contoso.com/adfs/ls endpoint.  The wa=wsignoutcleanup is for the WS-Federation protocol.  Alot of times it looks like things are working if you use the wa=wsignoutcleanup but trust me it doesn't.  There are 4 cookies you usually get with SAML.  They are MSIS Auth cookies.  There are web application sessions cookies too.  Use the right URL to clean up things properly.

In the SAML protocol there is a concept of a SAML logout request and a SAML logout response.  This website has examples.  https://www.samltool.com/generic_slo_req.php

You should be able to see this with a SAML tracer.  There are a couple gotchas with SAML logout.  The name id you ask to logout has to be the exact same you used to login.

SAML logouts have to be signed 100% with a X.509 (SSL) Secure Socket Layer cryptography certificate to prevent spoofing. Good luck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).